# Type conversion of int and string, java

Tags: java, string, integer

last exam we had the exercise to determine the output of the following code:

```
System.out.println(2 + 3 + ">=" + 1 + 1);
```

My answer was `5 >= 2` but now I realize that this is the wrong answer. It should be `5 >= 11`. 
But why?

Comment: That is not valid Java code.  Please correct the syntax error.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think it may have to do with the fact that you switched over to a string part-way through the print. 2+3 it will treat as an integer, but once you hit the ">=" I think it switches over to considering the rest of the line as a string. so if you take the string ">=" plus the string "1" and "1" then you get >= 11. Again, I'm not certain of this, but it seems to make sense.

Comment: Upvoted just for your nickname!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that your syntax is :

```
System.out.println(2 + 3 + ">=" + 1 + 1);
```

expressions are evaluated from left to right, in this case 2 + 3 get summed to 5 and when "added" to a string result in `"5 >="`, which when added to 1 gives `"5 >= 1"`, add another 1 and your result is: `"5 >= 11"`

Comment: yes!! one of those things that you just can't remember when you really need to :p

Comment: No, this isn't the result of "precedence"; that's when you have two different operators (e.g. `+` and `*`) and one of them is handled first. What's at work here is left-to-right **associativity**.

Answer (score 12):

Because "adding" a string to anything results in concatenation.  Here is how it gets evaluated in the compilation phase:

```
((((2 + 3) + ">=") + 1) + 1)
```

The compiler will do constant folding, so the compiler can actually reduce the expression one piece at a time, and substitute in a constant expression.  However, even if it did not do this, the runtime path would be effectively the same.  So here you go:

```
((((2 + 3) + ">=") + 1) + 1) // original
(((5 + ">=") + 1) + 1)       // step 1: addition      (int + int)
(("5>=" + 1) + 1)            // step 2: concatenation (int + String)
("5>=1" + 1)                 // step 3: concatenation (String + int)
"5>=11"                      // step 4: concatenation (String + int)
```

You can force integer addition by sectioning off the second numeric addition expression with parentheses.  For example:

```
System.out.println(2 + 3 + ">=" + 1 + 1);   // "5>=11"
System.out.println(2 + 3 + ">=" + (1 + 1)); // "5>=2"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Number+number=number
number+string=string
string+number=string
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is evaluated from left to right. You concatenate`"1"` to `"5 >="` and finally `"1"` to `"5 >= 1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's read it one token at a time from left to right:

The first literal encountered is an integer, `2`, then a `+`, then another integer, `3`. A `+` between two integers is addition, so they are added together to be `5`.

Now we have `5`, an integer, then a `+`, then a String `">="`. A `+` between an integer and a String is a concatenation operator. So the Strings are combined to form `"5>="`.

Then we have `"5>="`, a String, a `+`, and then an integer, `1`. This is String concatenation again. So the result is `"5>=1"`.

Finally we have  `"5>=1"`, a String, a `+`, and the a `1`. his is String concatenation again. So the result is `"5>=11"`.